# Vuejs filter textarea

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a textarea with v-model:

```
<textarea v-model="text"></textarea>
```

How I can filter this textarea in vue? I need prevent this quotes of html:

```
&amp;amp;#039;id&amp;amp;#039;
```

Comment: Please add a relevent code snippet of what you have already tried.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a watcher property to watch any changes in textarea and prevent that quotes for example :

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      text: ''
    }
  },
  watch: {
    text(newVal, oldVal) {
      let p = ["&amp;", "amp;", "#039;", "id&amp;", "amp;", "#039;"]

      if (p.some(v => {
          return newVal.includes(v);
        })) {

        this.text = oldVal;
      }

    }

  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <textarea class="form-control" v-model="text"></textarea> {{text}}
</div>
```

Comment: Why when I add `&` in textarea, after send form Vue automatically paste `&amp`?

Comment: i do not understand your question, please explain more that in your question and give more details